# AS3: How to properly delete all properties of an object or all keys in a dictionary?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

To delete all the properties of an `Object`, I've been using a for...in loop to iterate through the properties and delete them. I've been doing the same thing with keys in a `Dictionary`. I recently read a comment where someone said that if you delete the properties/keys of an object/dictionary as you're iterating through it, it might miss some of the properties/keys. Is this true? Would it be better to use a for...in loop to push each property/key into an array, then delete them that way?

Comment: Can a simple `currentOBJ = new Object()` not **reset** your currently used object (thus deleting the properties)? Or maybe even `currentOBJ = {};` to avoid using _new_, if preferred.

Comment: @VC.One If we are talking about a simple project, you are probably right. But with an application, that is supposed to run an indefinite amount of time, it is a good idea not to just rely on Garbage Collector, but actually to manually disassemble every little thing like reducing **Array**s to 0 length, removing all keys from generic **Object**s, assigning **null** to class properties, specifically unsubscribing all the event handlers and removing all the children from ant **Sprite** or **MovieClip** you are throwing away.